# Adding application to registry for run at startup using c#

Tags: c#, registry, startup

I have added this code for run at start up

```
public static void AddApplicationToStartup()
{
    using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true))
    {
        key.SetValue("My Program", "\"" + Application.ExecutablePath + "\"");
    }
}
```

and i have called this function at the very first line of Main function.
the problem is this will run every time. but how can we check that this application is already added to registery??

Comment: Please add a config setting to your program, allowing users to disable that feature (You could save it being set by making your autorun enty use an empty string). Not doing so is extremely annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Before calling your function for setting key in registry. Check the existing registry by using following:

```
Registry.GetValue(keyName, valueName, defaultValue);
```

MSDN Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue.aspx